# MS Teams PWA captures all keys on sway

Tags: linux, google-chrome, microsoft-teams, web-application, brave

How do I turn off capturing some keybindings in brave/chrome installed PWA app?

I have installed MS Teams in Brave trough `settings->more tools->create shortcut`.
Using wayland, sway and pipewire I can now share my screen when enabling `chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer`.

Problem is, that when I have the focus on the ms teams app window, it captures all keys that I'm typing. So in sway there is eg. `super+1` to change to workspace 1. Instead it writes `1` to chat. Or `super+shift+3` to move the window to workspace 3. Instead it writes `#`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the chrome code, not in Sway. It was reported as a problem on KDE as well. The mainline bug can be found on [chromium bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1338554). This was introduced by [this patch](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/3615269) which enables using the [keyboard-shortcuts-inhibit](https://wayland.app/protocols/keyboard-shortcuts-inhibit-unstable-v1) wayland protocol, if available. The reasoning behind using this is not entirely clear to me, even though it is somehow explained in the mentioned bug report.

The workaround for this problem on Sway is to disable this extension for the chrome windows by adding something like this to you sway config (I had to restart the PWA app after reloading the sway config for it to work):

```
for_window [app_id="^chrome-.*"] shortcuts_inhibitor disable
```

You can also try to be more specific and leverage the fact that for PWAs chrome uses the app_id like this - chrome-<app_id>-<profile_name> and use:

```
[app_id="^chrome-.*-.*$"]
```

---

**In brave**, all the above applies except that the prefix is `^brave-.*`.

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't do anything :/

Comment: Did you remember to reload the sway and then restart the chrome? I only had one PWA and no other Chrome instances so I'm not sure if killing all chrome might be required.

In any case, if it doesn't work even after restarting all of that, then verify that the app_id you are using matches the one that PWA has, by using "swaymsg -t get_tree" and finding your app.

Comment: Ok so the regex wasn't correct maybe. Now I have it like this:
`for_window [app_id="^chrome-"] shortcuts_inhibitor disable`

Comment: The asterisk must not be escaped in the regex.